# How to clear Firestore persistence data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My iOS app's firestore cache seems to have got out of sync with Firestore. As a result I've had to disable persistence. Is there anyway to reset the cache? And is there a way to make sure it's constantly in sync? All I did was delete documents from the database!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is now a feature in the API for clearing persistence.  It is not recommended for anything but tests, but you can use

```
firebase.firestore().clearPersistence().catch(error => {
  console.error('Could not enable persistence:', error.code);
})
```

It must run before the Firestore database is used.

Comment: Why is it not recommended for anything but tests? Would it not be beneficial to clear the cache between sessions (i.e., on sign-out)?

Comment: I use it and its just simply clean up all data in firestore emulator ,I guess this method only supported in emulator for test purpose,not for cleanup firestore persisted cache in app. Its pretty quite confusing name for a mobile client sdk. 

Answer (score 2):

There's no API for manipulating the local cache in any way.  The Firestore SDK chooses what to store based on queries that you perform.

On Android, users can manually clear the local data for an app without uninstalling it.  This will remove all the data locally stored by the app.

If you have a specific use case, please feel free to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: I just did the feature request :)

Comment: Did you find any solution to it?

Comment: I found it goes out of sync if you are performing operations directly in firestore (not from app device). I deleted data in firestore, then installed the app to a new device, and the new device did not receive any data from firestore, clearing the apps data fixed it.  I think if you are performing operations directly in firestore, setting persistence enabled to false seems to be required to get the cache in sync again.

Comment: Any best-practices surrounding logout and Firestore cache? I imagine it is bound to the Google Account, but if you have a custom system layer providing auth and accounts on top of that (say a web system) then could it be possible to see more than one (web system) user operating with the same cache of data?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson  is there any feature added regarding this in the firestore?