# Where does firestore store cache on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore with an Android app and I was testing my "offline mode". I was trying to delete cached data without code and I couldn't. I tried to "force close" my app, and I even tried the "Clear Cache" option within the Android's app info page, and no luck.

Do you know where does firestore store cache? Is "Clear Storage" the only solution to completely delete cache with no code? I'm using a OnePlus 6 device with android 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore uses SQLite as its persistence layer.  The database is stored in the usual area for persistent databases, which is not in the app "cache" folder.  You will indeed have to wipe the entire app storage if you want to remove Firestore's cache.

The SDK does provide a [method to clear persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929728/how-to-clear-firestore-persistence-data), but you should be aware that this is for testing only and should not be used in a shipping app.

Comment: Thanks Doug!. Why can I not use the method to clear persistence? Let's say I have some cached data but then the user logs out... I would like to delete all possible data from it, and that would include firestore cache as well

Comment: All I can tell you is to read the documentation for clearPersistence.  If you really need to know why, you will have to ask the Firebase team directly.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#clearPersistence()