# react-native how to remove persistence on firebase snapshot

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am little confused.
I am listening to firebase snapshot with sample code below

```
unsubscribe = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('collection')
    .doc(id)
    .onSnapshot(
        function(doc) {
            // other code
        },
    );
```

This will listen to the collection if there's new item for the specific id.
Then, closing the app will unsubscribe to the snapshot

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        if (unsubscribe) {
            unsubscribe()
        }
    }
}, []);
```

It is working fine.

However, given the scenario.

1. If the snapshot triggered (eg. { value: 1 }) and then I closed the app.
2. Removed the value on the firebase for the specific id. (meaning the id should not received the item)
3. Re-open the app
4. I still get the previous value which is { value: 1} and then get the newest value which is undefined (since i removed the value)

Is the value persists on the app? How can I remove this one upon re-opening of the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[From this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56840788/16818500)

There is now a feature in the API for clearing persistence. It is not recommended for anything but tests, but you can use

```
firebase.firestore().clearPersistence().catch(error => {
  console.error('Could not enable persistence:', error.code);
})
```

It must run before the Firestore database is used.