# How can I Get more than 5 Documents from a Firestore query?

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, leaderboard

I've been working with Firebase Firestore to make a leaderboard for a game I'm making.  Here is part of my code:

```
public void receiveFirestoreData()
    {   //count how many documents have been given loaded
        int counter = 0;
        Query allUsersQuery = db.Collection("Usernames");
        allUsersQuery.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            QuerySnapshot allUsersQuerySnapshot = task.Result;
            foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in allUsersQuerySnapshot.Documents)
            {
                //add one to the counter with each iteration
                counter++;
                Debug.Log("counter: " + counter.ToString());
                Debug.Log($"Document data for {0} document:"+ documentSnapshot.Id);
                
                //the gamer tag of the user
                string username = documentSnapshot.Id;
                GameObject user = allHighScores.transform.Find(helperFunction(counter)).gameObject;
                user.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = username;
                
                Dictionary<string, object> encryptedScores = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in encryptedScores)
                {
                    GameObject score = user.transform.Find("Score").gameObject;
                    string decryptedScore = AesOperation.DecryptString(ScoreManager.key, pair.Value.ToString());
                    score.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = decryptedScore;

                
                }    
                
            }
        });
        
    }
```

In it, I get a snapshot of a Collection called "Usernames" and Documents which are in it.  I have 8 Documents in the Collection when I look at it in the Firebase Console.  However, the above code always results in 5 Documents given to me.  I don't get the final 3.  How can I fix this?
Doing some research I found out that maybe Firestore has a limit of 10 Documents you can get at once?  I'm not sure if that's true.  Most of the above code is from the Firebase Docs.  Thank you for your help!

It's been hard for me to figure out what it going on here!  I tried to see if it was slow internet connectivity but I don't think that's the culprit.  I also tried deleting and rewriting the Firestore database but that changed nothing.

Also, the function helperFunction is just a function for me to show each username and score in the correct place in my game hierarchy

Comment: Nothing in the code you show explains why you'd only get 5 documents. The `allUsersQuery.GetSnapshotAsync()` should get all documents from `Usernames`. Firestore also doesn't have any built-in limits that would explain this behavior. Could it be that the device you're running on is not connected to the network or is having low connectivity? In that case, you might be seeing the results from the on-device cache that Firestore creates - which were previously put there when the device *did* have good connectivity.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your comment!  It's possible you're correct because the WiFi I was on was not good.  However, right now I'm connected to a fast WiFi network and I'm still getting the same 5 Documents.  Is there a way I can delete the cache? Is it possible to prevent the device from making a cache in the first place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929728/how-to-clear-firestore-persistence-data?

Comment: I don't think its the cache that's the problem.  I deleted the only collection in my database and my app populated it with new data.  Still, I only receive 5 Documents

Comment: Hmm... in that case I have no idea where the problem occurs. Firestore's server definitely doesn't have an arbitrary 5 document limit, and I don't think any of its SDKs do either. Hopefully somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: When I delete all the code that has anything to do with outside the query, I get all 10 documents.  However, in that case my problem is "how can I assign variables to this data?" Dictionaries do not work, only text does.  I'm not sure why

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I believe I've found the culprit.  My code is being executed before I receive all the data from Firestore.  What code should I use to wait to receive the complete snapshot?  I've looked around and I can't find any code in C Sharp

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what those last two comments mean. Words are probably not an ideal way to explain your new findings, so I recommend updating your question with an updated [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably one that shows the problematic behavior with logging output (that's the only way we're ever gonna be looking at he exact same code and output).